# forEach push twice the same element

Tags: typescript

I'm making a push into a var for generate an array of events, for this I have this array:

```
var tasks = [
  {
    "TaskId": "4546b60a-823a-4892-931a-bc322a315aef",
    "Name": "Tarea2",
    "StartDateGoal": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "EndDateGoal": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    "TaskId": "af71c28d-6580-4249-9987-234ff8254f83",
    "Name": "theth",
    "StartDateGoal": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "EndDateGoal": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
  }
]
```

and with it I need to generate events with this structure:

```
  let event = {
          title: "", 
          start: "", 
          end: "",
        }
```

So for it I'm making a forEach with a push into, but for some reason it is returning me the last task twice, this is my push:

```
   this.tasks.forEach( task => { 
          event.title = task.Name
          event.start = task.StartDateGoal
          event.end = task.EndDateGoal
          this.events.push(event)
        })
```

and it is returning me it:

```
   [
  {
    "title": "theth",
    "start": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "theth",
    "start": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2021-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

I have no Idea why it is happening, so how can I fix it?

Comment: @szx I already change it for var but its the same result

Comment: `this.events.push({...event})` use destruct to clone object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the `event` variable outside the `forEach`.  So there's only one "event" object and with each iteration of the loop you are modifying that object.  Each value in the array is just a reference to the same object.

Simply create a new object with each iteration of the loop.  You don't even really need the `event` variable, you can just create each object in-line:

```
this.tasks.forEach(task => { 
  this.events.push({
    title: task.Name,
    start: task.StartDateGoal,
    end: task.EndDateGoal
  });
});
```